# SDL2 trash cleanup for texture clips

Tags: c++, memory-management, sdl-2

I am writing an SDL2 C++ program that creates clips from large sprite sheets and has a system loop to render them. So, only a few textures but many, many derivative clips. As I understand it, these are the facts

1. the advantage using clips is that  copying a portion of the larger original texture is more efficient
2. loading the texture and clipping is best done before the system loop,
3. memory leaks prevention/trash cleanup dictates you destroy and recreate textures with every loop cycle,
4. after the loop ends, you should destroy everything: windows, renderer, and textures

Obliterating everything I understand. But how does the cyclical cleanup within the loop work with clips, and what should go before, within and after my loop? Am I supposed to be destroying and recreating all the clips once every cycle, every time I render present a new batch onscreen, or cleanup after each individual clip? Am I supposed to destroy the original textures as well and then recreate the clips?

Comment: Point 3 is super weird. Why would you destroy textures only to immediately create them again? You don't have to keep original smaller textures if you don't use them.

Comment: As I understand, it's to clear memory space taken up by the previous copy of each texture before you remake/rerender it each time you run the cycle.

Comment: What do you call a clip?

Comment: A copy of a small piece of the original texture. The process is known as "clipping" the texture, hence clips.

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what you're talking about. Recreating textures makes no sense to me. Could you edit in your code/pseudocode?

Comment: There is no code or pseduocode. I am asking a question based around a set of postulates/assumptions, which I list.

Comment: Then generally this assumption is incorrect - there is no reason to delete and recreate a texture if you're going to use it again on next frame. There are many "what if"s about it though, like "what if i don't need it on next frame but in next 5 seconds", but that have to be very specific.